# sending email from external smtp server

Tags: php, smtp

I'm trying to use the php script below to send mail from an external server:

```
<?php
$recipient="dwqchen@gmail.com"; 
$subject="Website to customer";
$message="Customer Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n";
$message.="Customer Email: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
$message.="Customer Message: ".$_POST['msg']."\r\n"; 
$mailheader="From: <maria@comcast.net> \r\n";
$mailheader.="Reply to ".$_POST['email'];
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sending mail from website to Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Thanks, <strong><?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></strong>, for your message.</p>
<p>Your email address: <strong><?php echo $_POST['email']; ?></strong></p>
<p>Your message: <br/><?php echo $_POST['msg']; ?></p>
</body>
<html>
```

I got the following error message:

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sendmail.php on line 9

My php.ini is set to:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.comcast.net
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = maria@comcast.net
```

Could anyone tell me what I should do please?  Thanks.

Comment: Your $mailheader is not passed to the function mail() is that normal?

Comment: I used "mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader)" initially.  The error message was "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sendmail.php on line 9"

Comment: `;` is a comment character in php.ini. You could try removing it before the `sendmail_from` and then you won't have to set it in php every time.

Comment: I removed the ";" in php.ini.  Now the error message becomes

Comment: I removed the ";" in php.ini. Now the error message becomes "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sendmail.php on line 9"

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the php `mail()` is for local mail server, if you want to send with external smtp server, please have a see at http://swiftmailer.org/, I am using it with gmail account

Comment: Try `SMTP = "smtp.comcast.net"`